# Spaces between editor line numbers intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

As you can see there is a lot of "Spaces" between editor line numbers and i dont know how to disable or delete that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure which gaps you're referring to - the space between consecutive numbers, or the non-consecutive line numbers. The first one, you'll need to show what is in your editor to see why there are gaps. The second one - that's code folding https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Maybe I was not very clear, if you look between the enumerations of the editor lines there are spaces between them for some reason and I can't find how to deactivate it. Instead of all of them having the same spaces, there are some that have bigger spaces.

Comment: I think there is some sort of rendering problem because the gaps are meant to display [inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inlay-hints.html). See if you can turn them off in preferences (Editor | Inlay Hints)?

Comment: @user11350388 omg dude i think is that, cause i desactivated Inlay Hints and the lines are together [image](https://imgur.com/GiM4854). i'm gonna check it out more closely but, seriusly thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to @user11350388 I finally found the problem and basically it was cause of a property in Editor|Inlay Hints. Specifically in Code vision -> Code author where if I deactivate it the problem is solved by magic.

[image]

as you can see on the left every "X" lines there is a considerable space between them but if I deactivate the mentioned property it is solved.

[image]

Comment: Please don't provide either of these: *terminal commands*, *code*, *error messages* as images. Always include them as a **text** formatted appropriately.

Comment: There was an issue which will be fixed with the next IDE update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291945/Spurious-un-cursorable-white-line-between-javadoc-and-method

Comment: Extra lines are added when those hints are displayed with the "default" option. You can change it to use the "Right" position, which displays them "inline" instead.